# Question about sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, definition

A sequence can be defined as a function with the natural numbers as its domain. For instance, if $f(n)$ is a sequence then it is true that: $$f: \Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb R$$
Therefore, from definition a sequence $f$ is an infinite "set" of real numbers in a specific order. How come then there are people talking about "finite" sequences (For example, Sal in khan academy said the term in his first Algebra I sequence video). Doesn't that contradict the definition above?

Comment: an example $f(n)=1+(-1)^n$

Comment: One certainly can restrict the domain to a subset (*including a finite subset*) of $\Bbb N$ if one desired.  Commonly the domain will be all of $\Bbb N$, but as is the case for finite sequences it is merely a finite subset of $\Bbb N$, usually of the form $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$.  Also, there is no requirement that the codomain be $\Bbb R$, that would only be required for *real sequences*, but you could have sequences of letters, of complex numbers, of colors, etc...

Comment: Besides finite sequences, the concept of [transfinite sequences](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22transfinite+sequence%22) is also quite common. What you need to keep in mind is that terms used in a certain book are not always "set in stone" outside that book. For pedagogical reasons, textbook authors and teachers usually do not overload students with all the ways a certain term is used in actual practice.

Comment: No, not every sequence is a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: Finite sequences are n-tuples or eventually constant sequences.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!

Comment: @WilliamElliot I do get the n-tuple part. I don't get the second part. I can construct an infinite sequence with all the terms being the same number (let's say real). For example: $f(n)=k , k \in \mathbb R ,  \forall n \in \mathbb N $ which is a constant sequence.

Comment: @janmarqz what do you mean with this example. As I can understand, it is a sequence that alternates the real numbers 0 an +2. Specifically, if $ n \in \mathbb N $ this continues to infinity.

Comment: @AndrewMastronikolis: it is an example of a finite sequence but non constant

Comment: It seems that we have different definitions about a finite sequence. When I use finite sequence I mean that the sequence has a finite number of terms. And this is how Jose Carlos Santos defined it it the answers. What's your definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question.

You will often encounter essentially unimportant ambiguities of this kind in mathematics. The common word "sequence" sometimes means only infinite sequences, sometimes only finite, sometimes either. You can usually tell from the context. If there's any doubt, the writer should make his or her meaning clear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

A finite sequence (by the way, I do not use that expression) of real numbers is a function from $\{1,2\ldots,n\}$ into $\mathbb R$, for some natural number $n$.